# how to save 2 attributes using 1 function to core Data (Swift4)

Tags: ios, core-data, attributes, save, swift4

My code right now is causing a runtime error. It works perfectly with just 1 attribute but with 2 it crashes. I have also attached a photo of my coreData file below.

```
class firstVC : UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var enterText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var enterNumber: UITextField!


var itemsName : [NSManagedObject] = []
var textFieldz : UITextField!
@IBAction func sam(){
    save()
}


func  save() {
    let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appD.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Team", in : context)!

    let theTitle = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    theTitle.setValue(enterText.text, forKey: "lorde")
    theTitle.setValue(enterNumber.text, forKey: "num")



    do {
        try context.save()
        itemsName.append(theTitle)


        ////
    }
    catch {
        print("Tom Corley")

    }




}}
```

pic of coreData file. 
[image]

Comment: What is the crash (error message and/or stack dump)  and which attribute of the two is the new one that causes the crash?

Comment: The attribute that causes the crash is the second one num.

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: This is the error: 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Team 0x600000094dc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: the entity Team is not key value coding-compliant for the key "num".'

Comment: Do you generate your NSManagedObject subclasses manually or automatically, maybe your code is not in synch with your model after you added the second attribute? Check that there is no extra space after "num" in your attribute definition

Answer (score 0):

I see you have tagged your question swift4 so why not work directly with the entity class

```
let team = Team(context: context)
team.lorde = enterText.text
team.num = enterNumber.text
```

This way you avoid any spelling error and can find errors at compile time rather than runtime.